# VDSL SNR and line attenuation

Tags: internet, connection, dsl, broadband, vdsl

Hi everyone I have a question that I couldn’t find the answer to it
I have a VDSL connection. The modem shows that current speed is at 80mbit download but I can never even get close to it and there are so many packet errors and max SNR margin is at 7. After sometime using the net the SNR margin even gets lower to near 3 and sooo many error packets.
Line attenuation is good like 13.5 but SNR is so bad.
How can I fix that? Does changing copper wires all along help with this? cause line attenuation is great but snr is terrible or it will not help at all?

Comment: Have you talked to your ISP?

Comment: Yes they seem to not know much and do. They just try to lower speed to increase SNR.

Comment: What is the make/model of your modem/router?

Comment: Where could noise be entering the line? Are you in an electrically-noisy area, such as near a factory? Is all wiring between the entrance panel and the PC in good shape, and well-terminated (i.e., at the proper impedance)?

Comment: No not really and also my line attenuation which as I know is the noise is good. The problem is just SNR and constant packet errors and SNR getting worse over time.

Comment: It is TP-link TD-W9960 v1.2